# How to center all divs in bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to center align every divs in Bootstrap3. To make it an accounting report. There're 3 level of divs - Header, subheader and detail list. Each level I use `col-md-*` to limit the width. I've tried `text-align` but it's not help.

Here's the code :

```
<div class="container">
<div class="header text-info">
        <h1>Heading</h1><br />
        <h2>Acc. Type</h2><br />
        <h3>Month</h3>
    </div>
<legend>Income</legend>
    <div class="acc-content row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <b>col-md-12</b>
            <span class="pull-right">#@#</span>
        </div>
    </div>
<legend>Expense</legend>
    <div class="acc-content row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <b>col-md-12</b>
            <span class="pull-right">#@#</span>
        </div><!-- /col-md-12 -->
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <b>col-md-10</b>
            <span class="pull-right">#@#</span>
        </div><!-- /col-md-10 -->
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <b>col-md-8</b>
            <span class="pull-right">#@#</span>
        </div><!-- /col-md-8 -->
    </div><!-- /acc-content -->
</div>
```

DEMO : http://fiddle.jshell.net/nobuts/mshwa1yt/1/show/ (please view in desktop).

I expect all the divs to center aligned like this : (red border is just a test)

Please be adviced.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `col-md-offset-*`. For example:

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
```

and

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
```

You must also change your `margin: 5px` on `.acc-content div[class*='col-md-']` to `margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px` because it overwrites Bootstrap's `margin-left` for `col-md-offset-*`.

- DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/mshwa1yt/5/embedded/result/
- DOCS: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting

Comment: @Wilf Fixed. There was an issue in your css.

Comment: Mooseman, yeah it's about my css. And it works now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

using block-center class wrapping using row

Answer (score 0):

all the col classes from bootstrap have the float left property. either remove them (not adivsed) and add `margin:auto` to the divs...or add more divs:

if u have a col-8 add col-2 left and col-2 right (offsets)...so you keep the grid system in place

Comment: It will affect other divs badly any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to the `div`s:

```
.acc-content div[class*='col-md-'] {
    float: none;
    margin: 5px auto;
}
```

First one overwrites the `float: left` rule that's pretty much the opposite of center aligning it, the second one actually aligns it to center.

Comment: Works great for me: http://fiddle.jshell.net/dakp02pL/1/ You probably added the rule before you overwrote it with your own `margin:5px;` rule..

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 3 has a mixin called center-block found in utilities.less.

First, add class **center-block** to elements that should be centered.

Then, if using Less, add to CSS:

```
.center-block {
.center-block();
}
```

If using plain CSS, add:

```
.center-block {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in this example replace this

```
     <div class="col-md-10">
        <b>col-md-10</b>
        <span class="pull-right">#@#</span>
    </div><!-- /col-md-10 -->
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <b>col-md-8</b>
        <span class="pull-right">#@#</span>
    </div><!-- /col-md-8 -->
```

with this

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <b>col-md-10</b>
        <span class="pull-right">#@#</span>
    </div><!-- /col-md-10 -->
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <b>col-md-8</b>
        <span class="pull-right">#@#</span>
    </div><!-- /col-md-8 -->
```

add class col-md-offset-"number of cols" to col- divs